NodesJs - Quero deletar e chamar uma rota que está no mesmo ejs após deletar registro
Gostaria de após deletar o registro, que fosse direcionada para a mesma rota "/" que está neste mesmo arquivo.
Está acontecendo que após deletar e pedir para fazer o res.render("/") ele pega outra rota de outro arquivo. Se eu faço o res.redirect também não estou tendo sucesso.
'''
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const moment = require('moment')
const connection = require("../database/database")
const { default: slugify } = require("slugify")
router.get('/',(req,res) => {
resultado = connection.query("Select * from categories order by id desc",(err,results,fields) =>{
res.render("index", {resultado: results})})
})
router.get('/novo',(req,res) => {
res.render('novo')
// res.send("Página Nova Categoria")
})
router.post("/save",(req,res) =>{
title = req.body.title
slug = slugify(title)
createdAt = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
updatedAt = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
connection.query("Insert into categories (title,slug,createdAt,updatedAt) values (?,?,?,?)",[title,slug,createdAt,updatedAt],(err,result) =>{
        res.render("edit")
    })

})
router.post('/delete',(req,res) => {
id = req.body.id
/* connection.query("Delete from categories Where id= ?",[id],(err,result) =>{
})
*/
res.router("/")
})
module.exports = router
'''

Descobri. Estava fazendo res.router("/") e na verdade deveria ser res.redirect("./")
